# When I open a csv, process the file and drop colums, the file size gets bigger

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, size, data-processing

I am opening a 1GB csv file to merge 6 columns, which will become three columns after the process. Even-though I am not doing any string conversions, file size become bigger at the end of the process.

I have tried copying the columns to a new column and dropping the existing once whether it'll make any change but it didn't.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('xxxxxxx.csv', low_memory=False)

dataset.TAM_duration = dataset.TAM_duration.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_mediaDuration)
dataset.TAM_Event_Date = dataset.TAM_Event_Date.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_Event_Date)
dataset.TAM_MediaID = dataset.TAM_MediaID.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_MediaID)

dataset.rename(columns={'TAM_duration': 'combo_duration', 'TAM_Event_Date': 'combo_Event_date','TAM_MediaID':'combo_MediaID'}, inplace=True)

dataset.rename(columns={'TAM_duration': 'combo_duration', 'TAM_Event_Date': 'combo_Event_date','TAM_MediaID':'combo_MediaID'}, inplace=True)

dataset.drop(['VPM_mediaDuration','VPM_Event_Date','VPM_MediaID'], axis=1,inplace=True)

dataset2.to_csv('cccccccccc.csv',sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `.fillna()` with other values from the `DataFrame`. These lines:

```py
dataset.TAM_duration = dataset.TAM_duration.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_mediaDuration)
dataset.TAM_Event_Date = dataset.TAM_Event_Date.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_Event_Date)
dataset.TAM_MediaID = dataset.TAM_MediaID.fillna(value=dataset.VPM_MediaID)
```

are replacing empty characters (i.e. `NA` values) from the DataFrame with "something" (I don't know what) that should increase the size of your CSV file.

Comment: NA is filled with an existing value of another column. Basically I merge 2 columns and drop one. Should that not decrease the size?